# Automating setup of scratch orgs

Tags: salesforcedx, node.js, sfdx-plugin

I want to write a script preferably in Node.js to automate `sfdx force:org:create`, `sfdx force:user:password:generate`, `sfdx:org:push` and, `sfdx force:user:permset:assign`. The script should take parameters such as devhub, alias duartiondays and so on and return the username and password.

I have found something [similar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-node) but since I'm not familiar with NodeJs I was wondering if someone out there has done this.

Do let me know if you need more context, thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use a shell script/batch file? Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Salesforce.org has a whole toolchain built to do this type of automation: [CumulusCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/). (I'm on the product team).

Comment: @sfdcfox no specific reason other than nodejs is easier to read and maintain because it is JS and we resonate with it but I'm open to other ideas as well. What I'm trying to achieve is just but running a command I want to set up an org for development. That's all but since we do this on a daily basis I was wondering if there is a way to run all the commands in one go.

Comment: David, yeah We use cumulus ci on the QA end but I'm looking for something that would require minimum setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fastest quickest setup option, in my opinion, is going to be a native command line script for your system. This is what things like bash and PowerShell have been doing really well since the [dawn of time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). And all you need is essentially a text file with the right perms (`sudo chmod u+x` on the script in your Unix-based os or in PowerShell running `Set-ExecutionPolicy` for the machine and making sure it is something other than `restricted`).

There are a lot of examples that work with the salesforce cli. The Sample App [gallery](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/sample-gallery) that the Salesforce dev evangelism team maintains has some kind of org init script in every sample app, such as [this](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/bin/orgInit.sh) orgInit.sh which does pretty much exactly what you want to do. And although it doesn't have all the parameters you want, there is an example of how to add one. I've also pulled together a bunch of examples of both `.sh` and `.ps1` scripts in a [repo](https://github.com/pchittum/everyday-sfcli). I've not done exactly what you want, but between those, you could probably hack something together quickly to have to use.

On the other hand, scripts like this are not as easily portable as the nodeJS one.

But if you're really keen on the nodeJS option, you could also create something with the Open CLI Framework ([oclif](https://oclif.io/)) that Heroku released about two years ago. I've been playing with it a bit, and it is really easy to work with and use and has features like logging, and the ability to pass both flags and parameters, as well as built-in documentation when you define a new flag. It even has the option for either a single-command CLI, or a pluggable one. And incidentally, it is the underlying engine for the salesforce cli.

For what you want, a script to orchestrate several salesforce cli commands, with minimal setup, I'd suggest using the [single](https://oclif.io/docs/single) command option (there is also a multi command pluggable option).

You'd need a current version of nodeJS installed then you could run this.

```
> npx oclif single my-org-tool
```

This will walk you through a set of options for how you want to write the script. You can mostly accept the defaults. But you will have to make a few choices.

- You'll be asked to pick a package manager. I pick npm at this point as I've not worked with yarn.
- You'll be asked if you want to use typescript. So pick your poison whether that or garden-variety JS.
- You'll be prompted if you want to have CI config files generated. It gives you four options. You can pick one, or all, or none.

[image: oclif setup options]

From there you can open up the project file and find `src/index.js` and you'll be able to begin writing your command.

The `index.js` will export a class which will have a single `.run` method which is where you put any logic. The class will also have a `.flags` property, in which you can put flags to represent the kinds of params you want to be able to use. You could also install and use the sfdx-node package to make it easy to invoke the commands from the salesforce cli.

There is a third option, which is actually creating a new plugin for the salesforce cli. You'd do this to invoke it.

```
> mkdir my-org-tool
> cd my-org-tool
> sfdx plugins:generate
```

This will create a project for you to develop your own custom plugin. One nice thing about this option is that it is bundled with and can be installed to run from the `sfdx` command.

Developing a plugin for `sfdx` you'll need to know typescript, and it uses the yarn package manager. I think there is also a bit of a learning curve to get to know all the features of the project and understand which things you need to touch to add new commands. This may prove more than your "quick setup" goal would allow. But if you want to dive in, there is a good introductory blog [post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/create-your-first-salesforce-cli-plugin.html) on the Salesforce developer blog.

So for my money, I'd either write the quick and dirty shell script, or do incrementally more work and get a whole CLI with oclif.

Comment: thank you for that detailed answer. I think I'm going to try the single-command option that looks easy to migrate once it has been set up.

Comment: how do I import the salesforce library? I have tried '@salesforce/command' but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I thought you were going to use the `sfdx-node` module. If you're going to directly use `@salesforce/command` I'd probably create a new sfdx plugin as opposed to oclif.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do now but I'm  facing a blocker please check this question - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/288272/automating-scratch-org-with-sfdx-plugins